# Requestig a blob with flask and javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask, request, blob

I am trying to build a flask app where the user says something into his microphone and the browser records it. After a certain amount of time the recording stops an d the user can click a submit button to send the audio to the server.

Until now I managed to make the part were the audio gets recorded and the recording stops after a certain time.

```
<form method="post" enctype=multipart/form-data action="/send">
        <div class="audio" id="audio"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var device = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})
            var items = []
            device.then( stream => {
                var recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
                recorder.ondataavailable = e=>{
                    items.push(e.data);
                    if (recorder.state == 'inactive')
                {
                    var blob = new Blob(items, {type: 'audio/webm'});
                    var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
                    var mainaudio = document.createElement('audio');
                    mainaudio.setAttribute('controls', 'controls');
                    audio.appendChild(mainaudio);
                    mainaudio.innerHTML = '<source src="'+URL.createObjectURL(blob)+'" type="video/webm"/>';
                   
                }
                }
                recorder.start(100);
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    recorder.stop();
                }, 5000);
            })       
        </script>
        <input type="submit">
        </form>
```

Now I would like the flask app to request the blob after clicking submit. I have tried that  but it does't work. So I did some research and fond out I can send it with ajax.

```
 $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/send',
                        data: blob,
                        cache: false,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false
                        }).done(function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    });
```

This is the request from flask:

```
@app.route('/send', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def submittwo():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        app.logger.debug(request.files['blob'].filename)
```

This also doesn't work. I get a bad request error. Could somebody explain to me why? I am still a beginner so I probably got some things wrong.

And thanks in advance for any help.